# Is an ancient text cited in "The Hunt for Red October" real?

Tags: the-hunt-for-red-october

In [one of the first scenes](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/h/hunt-for-red-october-script.html) of "The Hunt for the Red October" (emphasis mine):

> And what's this? "*I am become death, the destroyer of worlds*".
>
> It is **an ancient Hindu text** quoted by an American.
>
> American?
>
> Mmm. He invented the atomic bomb, and he was later accused of being a Communist.

Is this cite and text real? If yes, what is the exact source for this? Or is this just a fake prop for the movie?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's real.
A famous quote - Robert Oppenheimer, the 'father' of the atomic bomb, about the early tests in 1945.

It is an interpretation of a section of a Hindu text - the Bhagavad-Gita - far more philosophical than I'm going to attempt to transliterate, but in essence is a paraphrase of a 'feeling' inspired by it. Oppenheimer was reputedly attracted to Hinduism by the tests though was never a convert nor a believer. [That's a rabbit-hole I'm not going to run down;)

The easiest article I can find on it is from Wired [designed to be read by 'ordinary folks' not actual philosophers] ['Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds'. The story of Oppenheimer's infamous quote](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/manhattan-project-robert-oppenheimer)

Background -
[Wikipedia - J. Robert Oppenheimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Robert_Oppenheimer)
[Wikipedia - Bhagavad Gita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita)

He was later in life accused of being a communist - though that was in an era of extreme political paranoia & he was later 'forgiven' by Kennedy.

Comment: Don't you mean "pardoned by Kennedy"?  "Forgiven by Kennedy" implies that Kennedy stopped feeling angry at Oppenheimer, while "Pardoned by Kennedy" implies that Kennedy acted to give him a presidential pardon.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - I did chose my wording quite carefully. He could not be pardoned because he had committed no crime. Essentially he was ostracised, then later presented with a scientific honour, which signified the end of … McCarthyism & a decade of US paranoia [I was trying to avoid the actual political machinations of that era]